# Como manter o status anterior do checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox

Preciso manter o estado anterior da variável *checked* da `input` tipo `checkbox`, depois que a página é carregada. No estado atual, toda vez que ela é carregada, o `checkbox` volta a condição de desmarcado.
Gostaria de uma solução, através de JavaScript.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSS SWITCH</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function ChecksVerify() { 
     var aChk = document.getElementsByName("item");   
     for (var i=0;i<aChk.length;i++){   
       if (aChk[i].checked == true){   
         aChk[i].value = "?f=on"; 
       } else { 
         aChk[i].value = "?f=off"; 
       } 
       window.location.assign(aChk[i].value); 
       alert(aChk[i].value + " enviado");
     }
   }  
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="switch__container">
   <p align='center'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" onclick="ChecksVerify()">
    <label for="switch-shadow"></label>
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O protocolo HTTP é sem estado (*stateless*), ou seja, não armazena o estado e cada requisição se faz de forma independente das anteriores, porém você pode persistir o valor do *checkbox* no navegador do usuário com o [*localStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage). Conhece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o código abaixo que verifica se na URL da página existe o parâmetro `?f=on` que irá marcar a *checkbox*:

```
window.onload = function(){
    url_ = location.href;
    if(url_.indexOf("?f=on") != -1){
        document.getElementsByName("item")[0].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sempre tem um jeitinho maroto de se resolver @Dvdsamm... muito obrigado... eu nao sou muito familiarizado com programacao de web... eu gosto mesmo eh de assembler.

Comment: @songa rsrs... já tentei estudar Assembly há uns 25 anos atrás mas achei meio complicado. O que vc desenvolve com Assembler (Assembler e Assembly é a mesma coisa, não é)?

Comment: ooopzzzz... heheheheeeee... nao, nao eh!!! desculpe me pelo erro primario... assembly eh o termo q eu deveria ter ditto... eh a linguagem! o compilador eh q se chama assembler. bem! a pelo menos 45 anos q eu venho me distraindo com ela... acho q eh por isso, que nao me parece tao complicado assim! hoje em dia, tem mais utilidade para microcontroladores do que para microprocessadores.